# what of encryption protocol aws uses in transit within AWS resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security

I'm curious to know what kind of encryption aws uses in transit, say when a lambda reads/writes data from/to dynamo db. in general, how aws passes data between its resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: they use AES-256 to store data, and TLS protocol to send and receive data.

How I got there:
According to their own security blog *https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/importance-of-encryption-and-how-aws-can-help/*
They say: "*AES-256 is the technology we use to encrypt data in AWS, including Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3) server-side encryption.*" They don't say that AES-256 is only used for storage, but it seems that when it comes to moving data,  they use Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol, however they never directly talk about it. They just allude to it: "*When encrypting data in motion, AWS services use the Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol to provide encryption between your application and the AWS service*".